# Can decreasing sequence of sets with $A_i$ containing infinitely less elements than $A_{i-1}$ have finite limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, elementary-set-theory

An updated question to one I just asked. 
Can we have a decreasing sequence of sets $A_n$ each a subset of the natural numbers with all members containing countably infinitely many elements such that $A_i$ contains infinitely fewer elements than $A_{i-1}$ for all $i$ and whose intersection only has finitely many elements? If so, what are some examples?

Answer (score 1):

I assume by limit you mean the intersection of all the $A_i$?

Define
\begin{align*}
A_0&=\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]\\
A_1&=\mathbb{Q} \cap \left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]\\
A_2&=\mathbb{Q} \cap \left[0,\frac{1}{4}\right]\\
\vdots\\
A_1&=\mathbb{Q} \cap \left[0,\frac{1}{2^i}\right]\\
\vdots
\end{align*}
This is a decreasing sequence of countably infinite sets, $A_i \setminus A_{i-1}$ is countably infinite, and $\bigcap_{i=0}^\infty A_i=\{0\}$ is a finite set.

---

Edit since you've added that the $A_i$ should be subsets of the natural numbers. The simple answer is "yes," this is possible. The starting set $A_0$ (or $A_1$) in both answers to this question are countable, thus in bijection with the natural numbers. Let $\varphi:A_0 \to \mathbb{N}$ be such a bijetion. Then $\varphi(A_0)\supseteq \varphi(A_1)\supseteq \varphi(A_2) \supseteq \cdots$ is a decreasing sequences of countable sets, each containing countably infinitely fewer elements than the previous, and $\bigcap_{i=0}^\infty \varphi(A_i)=\varphi\left(\bigcap_{i=0}^\infty A_i\right)$ is a finite set.

For a more explicit example, take
\begin{align*}
A_0&=\mathbb{N}\\
A_1&=A_0\setminus \{2,4,6,\dots\}\\
A_2&=A_1 \setminus \{3,6,9,\dots\}\\
A_3&=A_2 \setminus \{5,10,15,\dots\}\\
\vdots\\
A_i&=A_{i-1} \setminus \{p_i,2p_i,3p_i,\dots\}\\
\vdots
\end{align*}
where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime. $A_{i-1}$ contains infinitely many multiples of $p_i$, for example $p_i, p_i^2,p_i^3,\dots$, which are all removed from $A_i$. Each natural number except $1$ is a multiple of some prime, so $\bigcap_{i=0}^\infty A_i=\{1\}$, which is finite.

Comment: Thanks! I don't suppose there is another natural example where $A_i$ doesn't rely on getting rid of all but finitely many multiples of some prime $p_i$?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by "limit" you mean "intersection", if not you need to clarify what notion of limit you have in mind.

For an example, consider the subsets $A_n$, $n = 1, 2, \ldots$,  of the  set $\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}$ of pairs of integers $(i, j)$ defined by:
$$
A_n = \{ (i,j) \mathrel{|} i = j = 0 \mbox{ or } j \ge n\}
$$
then
$$
A_n \mathop{\backslash} A_{n-1} = \{ (i, n) \mathrel{|} i \in \Bbb{Z}\}
$$
which is countably infinite and
$$
\bigcap A_n = \{(0,0)\}
$$
which is non-empty and finite. By leaving $(0, 0)$ out or including more points on the line $j = 0$ you could arrange for the intersection to have any finite number of elements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Apologies, I have edited the question so that each $A_i$ is a subset of the natural numbers and made it clear that I meant intersection.

Comment: You need to review your understanding of the term countable. Any countably infinite set is in 1-1 correspondence with the natural numbers. Hence, both the answers you have been given to the original question give answers to the new question. So it's over to you to explain why you need an example involving natural numbers.